# servlet/database: how to do fine-grained database connection and statement management (not bound to servlet lifetime)

Tags: database, scala, servlets, jetty, scalatra

### Question/Environment

The goal of my web application is to be a handy interface to the database at our company.

I'm using:

- [**Scalatra**](http://www.scalatra.org/) (as minimal web framework)
- [**Jetty**](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) (as servlet container)
- [**SBT**](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) (Simple Build Tool)
- [**JDBC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) (to interface with the database)

One of the requirements is that each user can manage a number of concurrent queries, and that even when he/she logs off, the queries keep running and can be retrieved later on (or their completion status checked if they stopped for any reason).

I suppose queries will likely have to run in their own seperate thread.

I'm not even sure if this issue is orthogonal or not to **connection pooling** (which I'm definitely going to use, BoneCP and C3PO seem nice).

### Summary

In short: **I need to have very fine-grained control over the lifetime of database requests, and they cannot be bound to the servlet lifetime**

What ways are there to fulfill my requirements? I've searched quite a bit on google and stack overflow and haven't found anything that addresses my problem, is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is missing from your stack is a scheduler. e.g http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

A rough explanation:

- Your connection pool (eg C3P0) will be bound to the application's lifecycle.
- Your servlets will be sending query requests to the scheduler (these will be associated to the user requesting the query).
- The scheduler will be executing queries as soon as possible, by using connections from the connection pool. It may also do so in a synchronized/serialized order (for each user).
- The user will be able to see all query requests associated with him, probably with status (pending, completed with results etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I must admit that it indeed looks like I could make use of some sort of scheduler! I'm not yet marking the answer as the correct one because there may be alternatives and I would like to hear of them also. Any experiences integrating with Jetty and/or Scalatra? (a cursory web search seems to indicate that it will be fine)

Comment: Quartz runs fine on tomcat, jetty, jboss etc. I don't know about Scalatra but I'm sure it's possible since this is Java.